# Migrating Subversion Server to Another

Tags: linux, svn

I have a server where I replaced the hard drive and now I'm rebuilding the server. I have all of the configuration and data of the old subversion setup+repos on the old hard drive. Is there anyway to bring the subversion content over to the new OS+hard drive without having to boot the drive and doing a svnadmin dump?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Copy the full repository filesystem. This should ensure you have not just the database, but any hook scripts and configuration. There are three consideration here:

- Stick with the same version of subversion (or make sure you run `svnadmin upgrade`)
- Run `svandmin verify` on the new copy before starting the server. It'll give you peace of mind that the whole thing is still intact.
- Make sure the new repo filesystem is owned by the user running the service (apache, svnserve)

Comment: Don't forget to add "remove the previous known host" on the client [since its pointing to the same name as before]

Comment: Good point. If you're using SSL and CNAMEs the host key will have changed.

Answer (score 2):

Copying everything into the proper locations should be enough. Just don't start svnserve until everything's in place.